# acceder a método si el objeto es una instancia de cierta clase en java

Tags: java, poo, método

tengo un array y quiero que acceda al primer objeto que sea de la instancia BarcoPesquero y si es asi que me muestre el metodo que tiene desde interfaz. lo que pasa es que no se como acceder al nombre que tiene esa posicion para llamar al metodo.
dejo el código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < barcos.length; i++) {
   if (contadorPesquero > 1) {
      if (barcos[i] instanceof BarcoPesquero) {
         System.out.println();
         contadorPesquero++;
      }
   }
}
```

el metodo al que quiero que acceda es :

```
public void msgSocorro(String mensaje) {

    System.out.println(alarma());
    System.out.println(mensaje);
}
```

osea que en la poscion[x] del array hay un objeto si sé que nombre tiene podré llamar al metodo de esa clase. Ya lo he intentado con barcos[i]._ _ _ pero no me aparece el metodo msgSocorro(String mensaje),

Espero que puedan ayudarme, Gracias

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ya me sale el método que necesitaba, gracias x contestar tan pronto !!!!SJuan76

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que hacer un casteo del objeto.

```
for (int i = 0; i < barcos.length; i++) {
    if (contadorPesquero > 1) {
        if (barcos[i] instanceof BarcoPesquero) {
        System.out.println();
        contadorPesquero++;

        BarcoPesquero barcoPesquero = (BarcoPesquero) barcos[i];
        barcoPesquero.msgSocorro("Hola Mundo!");

        // O más corto aun

        ((BarcoPesquero) barcos[i]).msgSocorro("Hola Mundo!);
    }
}
```